# Right align numbers in the centre of siunitx columns with long text in the header

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabu, dcolumn

In this MWE, I want to be able to wrap column headers while taking benefit of siunitx's S column for right aligning the numbers in the middle of the column. I have tried tabu, warpcol and dcolumn. None of them allows right-aligning numeric columns in the middle with a possibility of wrapping column headers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany,extrafontsizes,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{warpcol,array,tabulary,tabu,booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,polyglossia}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{@{}cSSS@{}}
\toprule
  {This is label of the first column} &
  {This is a long label} &
  {This column has a very very long long label} &
  {This is also not a short label} \\
\midrule
  Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
  Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
  Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `\thead` command from the [`makecell`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with use of `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany,extrafontsizes,article]{memoir}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,polyglossia}

%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c*{3}{S[table-format=3.0]}@{}}
\toprule
  \mcx{This is label of the first column} &
  \mcx{This is a long label} &
  \mcx{This column has a very very long long label} &
  \mcx{This is also not a short label} \\
\midrule
  Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
  Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
  Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very good. Trying to see if I can do this with tabu.

Comment: @user3395643, you are welcome, but there is policy, that instead saying "thank you" vote for question (by clicking on upper pen on the left top side of answer) and even accept it if it on the best way solve your problem. Regarding `tabu`: it was not mentioned in your question, so if you have specific question concerning it, please ask new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the `\thead` command from the [`makecell`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package as in the following.

The vertical and horizontal alignmen of the cells an be set individually. One can also set the cell width with `\thead[{{p{1in}}}]{Cell text}`, so the linebreaks are made automatically. see the documentation for more information.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cSSS@{}}
\toprule
  {\thead[t]{This is label of\\the first column}} &
  {\thead[t]{This is a\\long label}} &
  {\thead[t]{This column has\\a very very long\\long label}} &
  {\thead[t]{This is also not\\a short label}} \\
\midrule
  Item 1 & 10 & 12 & 15 \\
  Item 2 & 20 & 22 & 25 \\
  Item 3 & 30 & 32 & 35 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This requires manually determining the linebreaks. The solution by Zarko is much better.